# Latch locks when door handle pulled down

Tags: doors

Had our front door repainted (simply took off hinges and then replaced).  Now, when you open the door by pulling handle down the latch stays stuck such that you can't open it from the other side.  You have to pull up on the handle to release it and then the door can again be opened.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Pictures of the latch, and perhaps the make/model, would help.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the handle wasn't removed?  It's certainly a slight misalignment so that the latch is binding.  It could be that when it was rehung the door shifted slightly, or same thing with the handle being removed and replaced.  Either way, I'd loosen the handle enough that you can shift it very slightly but have it hold the position while you test it.  When you find a position that eliminates the binding (which I bet you do), retighten it.  If this doesn't seem to be the problem, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any WD-40? Some paint or something else may have gotten inside the mechanism. As Paul mentioned above, these are finicky and anything can throw them off.